# How do you .format when it comes to return statements in Python?

Tags: python, format

def budget(shopping: [None]) -> str:

this is my list:

```
shopping = ['1', ('242','18'), ('13','1'),('349','2')]
```

and i want to make that a parameter of a function and have a return statement that when printed, it would produce this :

```
Shopping Budget: Week 1 
Day = 242, Items = 18
Day = 13, Items = 1
Day = 349, Items = 2
```

im struggling to .format this correctly because my for loop would print "shopping budget" along with it.

i want to be able to return this function with any numbers in my list.

Comment: Where is your function, what defines each day?

Comment: @PacketLoss i just edited the page! i decided to change the weekdays, to something consistent in order to get helping with the formatting.

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given no function is provided, and the mention of a loop I am assuming you are trying to loop over the contents of `shopping` and format the response as posted.

You can do so below, only if the `shopping` list follows the same format entirely.

```
shopping = ['1', ('242','18'), ('13','1'),('349','2'), '2', ('1', '2'), ('3', '3'), ('4', '4')]
for week in shopping:
    if type(week) == str:
        print(f'Shopping Budget: Week {week}')
    else:
        print(f'Day = {week[0]}, Items = {week[1]}')
```

Explanation

---

1. `for week in shopping:` loop over each element in your `shopping` list
2. `if type(week) == str:` if the element is of type `str`
3. `print(f'Shopping Budget: Week {week}')` use `f-strings` to format string with the string value
4. `else` assumed iterable `print(f'Day = {week[0]}, Items = {week[1]}')` use `f-strings` to format with the tuple values

---

Output

```
Shopping Budget: Week 1
Day = 242, Items = 18
Day = 13, Items = 1
Day = 349, Items = 2
Shopping Budget: Week 2
Day = 1, Items = 2
Day = 3, Items = 3
Day = 4, Items = 4
```

---

Notes & Recommendations

Your shopping list isn't really storing the data very well. Checking the type of an element to dictate a change in week could cause issues if another element which is not a week, was stored as a string.

You should use a `dictionary` for this, it will be much more clear and concise.

```
shopping = {
    '1': {
        'day': 242,
        'items': 18
        },
    '2': {
        'day': 25,
        'items': 9
        },  
    }

shopping['1']['day']
```

Comment: `isinstance(week, str)` is more pythonic than `type(week) == str`, but good answer nonetheless.

Comment: I second the use of a dictionary . This seems like a perfect example of where to use one.

Comment: thank you so much guys! really informative

Answer (score 0):

I would print the first element, then loop through the rest and use f-strings (see: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

```
shopping = ['1', ('242','18'), ('13','1'),('349','2')]
print(f"Shopping Budget: Week {shopping[0]}")

for shopping_info in shopping[1:]:
  print(f"Day = {shopping_item[0]}, Items = {shopping_item[1]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the same as @PacketLoss but I used `.format` and checked against the `tuple` type instead.

```
shopping = ['1', ('242','18'), ('13','1'),('349','2')]


def budget(shopping=[None]) -> str:

    for element in shopping:

        if not isinstance(tuple, element):

            print('Week {}'.format(element))

        else:
            print('Day {}  Items: {}'.format(element[0], element[1]))

budget(shopping)
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping! rly appreciate it

Comment: Happy to help. Cheers!